# Free throws error on malloc'd object

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, free

I'm trying to free a malloc'd buffer I made for a string, but free() gives me an error.
As I see it, the value of the pointer doesn't change, and both arrays are malloc'd. So it should be possible to free them?
I can't think of what I have done wrong.

Here is the code:

```
/* dump
 * this function dumps the entry array to the command line
 * */
void dump(PasswordEntry * entries, int numLines) {
    int index = 0;
    unsigned char *hexSalt = malloc(SALT_HEX_LENGTH+1), *hexHash = malloc(MAX_HASH_LEN+1);  /* pointers for salt and hash, because we need them in hex instead of byte */

    while (index < numLines) {  /* go through every line */
        /* gets us the salt in hex */
        toHexBinary(hexSalt, entries[index].salt, SALT_HEX_LENGTH);
        /* gets us the hash in hex, with length according to set algorithm */
        toHexBinary(hexHash, entries[index].hash, (entries[index].algorithm == HASH_ALG_SHA1)?SHA1_HEX_LENGTH:SHA2_HEX_LENGTH);

        /* prints one line to command line */
        printf("%s: %s = %s (%s/%s)\n", entries[index].username, hexHash, (entries[index].password == NULL)?"???":entries[index].password, (entries[index].algorithm == HASH_ALG_SHA1)?"SHA1":"SHA2", hexSalt);
        index++;
    }

    /* don't need these anymore, we can free them */
    free(hexSalt);
    free(hexHash);
}

/* takes a string in binary and returns it in hex (properly escaped) */
unsigned char * toHexBinary(unsigned char * to, unsigned char * from, int length) {
    unsigned char c = '0';
    int second = 0, first = 0;
    if (to == NULL) {   /* if to is null, we need to allocate it */
        to = malloc(length+1);
    }

    to[length] = '\0';
    while (length-- > 0) {  /* go trough the string, starting at tthe end */
        length--;   /* we always need to read two characters */
        c = from[length/2]; 
        second = c % 16;
        first = (c - second) / 16;
        to[length] = toHex(first);
        to[length+1] = toHex(second);
    }

    return to;
}

/* takes a numeric character and returns it's hex representation */
char toHex(int c) {
    if (c < 10) return (char)(NUMBER_BEGIN + c);    /* if it is under 10, we get the appropiate digit */
    else return (char)(UPPER_BEGIN + (c - 10)); /* if it is over 10, we get the appropiate UPPERCASE character */
}
```

Here is the output of gdb:

```
Starting program: /crack -b ./hashes.txt 1 2

Breakpoint 1, dump (entries=0x604700, numLines=9) at crack.c:435
435     unsigned char *hexSalt = malloc(SALT_HEX_LENGTH+1), *hexHash = malloc(MAX_HASH_LEN+1);  /* pointers for salt and hash, because we need them in hex instead of byte */
(gdb) next
437     while (index < numLines) {  /* go through every line */
(gdb) p hexSalt
$1 = (unsigned char *) 0x604390 ""
(gdb) p hexHash
$2 = (unsigned char *) 0x604510 ""
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, dump (entries=0x604700, numLines=9) at crack.c:449
449     free(hexSalt);
(gdb) p hexSalt
$3 = (unsigned char *) 0x604390 "1234567890FEDCBA0000"
(gdb) p hexHash
$4 = (unsigned char *) 0x604510 "05F770BDD6D78ED930A9B6B9A1F22776F13940B908679308C811978CD570E057"
(gdb) next
450     free(hexHash);
(gdb) next
*** Error in `/crack': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000604510 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7602267 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:55
55  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: I recommend tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), it will help you a lot with memory errors like that. The most likely reason is that you overwrite the memory allocated, which Valgrind will help you find.

Comment: compiling the posted code causes the compiler to output several warnings.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use; `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) then fix those warnings.  For starters, post the definition of `passwordEntry`

Comment: when posting a question about a run time problem.  post the #include statements as part of the code, so we do not have to guess as to what the code is actually using

Comment: for readability and understandability by us humans, 1) separate code blocks (if, else, for, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line 2) follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: in C, parameters are passed by value, so these lines: `   if (to == NULL) {   /* if to is null, we need to allocate it */
        to = malloc(length+1);
    }` change what is on the parameter list, but not the callers' pointer.  The caller needs to pass the address of the pointer and the parameter should be: `unsigned char ** to`  then any references in the code should be: `*to`, or (*to)[x]` rather than just `to` or `to[x]`

Comment: the code block beginning with `while (length-- > 0) { ` is skipping every other character and seems to be trying to work with every char,  Overall, probably not what you want.

Comment: the #defines `UPPER_BEGIN` and `NUMBER_BEGIN`  add confusion to the code (and are not defined in the posted code.)  suggest using: `if( c< 10 ) return c+'0';  else return c+'A';

Comment: this line: `c = from[length/2];` is only going to look at every other char in the the first half of the input string pointed to by `from`.  probably not what you want.   Also, as an example, 5/2 and 4/2 will both result in looking at the same character.  Again, probably not what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
toHexBinary(hexHash, entries[index].hash, (entries[index].algorithm == HASH_ALG_SHA1)?SHA1_HEX_LENGTH:SHA2_HEX_LENGTH);
```

You allocate only `MAX_HASH_LEN+1` bytes for `hexHash`. But you are passing `SHA1_HEX_LENGTH` or `SHA2_HEX_LENGTH`.

If either of these values is greater than `MAX_HASH_LEN`, you have problem since the function `toHexBinary()` accesses `hexHash[MAX_HASH_LEN]`.  This is probably what happens. You can't pass a value that's greater than `MAX_HASH_LEN`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar error, "free(): invalid next size " and "../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.".
I was running a peripheral init job and then do ROS init and some other job.
The peripheral init job runs fine and the  ROS init job also works fine. But when do them together it always report this error.
finally I found this is a memory problem. in the malloc() I missed a * in sizeof() then the size of malloc memory is not correct.
just for someone who in the same boat.